# Splunk search if message is x for more than 5 minutes

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have two specific messages in splunk data that I'm searching for per user.

- on-screen
- off-screen

Anyone know how I can search in splunk for a user that is message="off-screen" for more than 5 minutes with a query checking every 2 minutes ?

```
index="document" (message="off-screen")
```

My query will be ran every 2 minutes so I want to check for the event with message off-screen. Then next time around check if 5 minutes have elapsed since the on-screen message was fired and that no on-screen event was fired in that time period for that user.
Is this possible ?

Comment: Did my answer below actually answer your question, or did I misunderstand what you were asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find off-screen messages that don't have an on-screen message within 5 minutes, then you can use a transaction.  Let's say your raw data is:

```
| makeresults count=10
| streamstats count
| eval _time=_time-(count*60)
| eval message=case(count=1,"on-screen",count=2,"on-screen",count=5,"off-screen",count=8,"off-screen",count=9,"on-screen",count=10,"on-screen")
| eval user=case(count=1,"Alice",count=2,"Bob",count=5,"Alice",count=8,"Bob",count=9,"Alice",count=10,"Bob")
| where NOT isnull(user)
| table _time user message
```

That would look like this:

| _time | user | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-28 13:57:50 | Alice | on-screen |
| 2021-05-28 13:56:50 | Bob | on-screen |
| 2021-05-28 13:53:50 | Alice | off-screen |
| 2021-05-28 13:50:50 | Bob | off-screen |
| 2021-05-28 13:49:50 | Alice | on-screen |
| 2021-05-28 13:48:50 | Bob | on-screen |

You need a transaction that gathers the user's cooresponding on-screen and off-screen messages as long as they are within 5 minutes.  But you need to keep the orphans where the off-screen message doesn't have a cooresponding on-screen message.  Then you filter out the transactions that have both and you get just the orphans:

```
message="off-screen" OR message="on-screen"
| transaction user maxpause=5m keeporphans=true startswith="message=off-screen" endswith="message=on-screen"
| where mvcount(message)<2
| table _time user message
```

That would produce this output:

| _time | user | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-28 13:50:50 | Bob | off-screen |

Here is a runnable example:

```
| makeresults count=10
| streamstats count
| eval _time=_time-(count*60)
| eval message=case(count=1,"on-screen",count=2,"on-screen",count=5,"off-screen",count=8,"off-screen",count=9,"on-screen",count=10,"on-screen")
| eval user=case(count=1,"Alice",count=2,"Bob",count=5,"Alice",count=8,"Bob",count=9,"Alice",count=10,"Bob")
| where NOT isnull(user)
| table _time user message

| search message="off-screen" OR message="on-screen"
| transaction user maxpause=5m keeporphans=true startswith="message=off-screen" endswith="message=on-screen"
| where mvcount(message)<2
| table _time user message
```